# Unsure why my sql update is not running even though there seem to be no problem

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin

```cs
private void UpdatePlayerScore(PlayerScore phsc)
{
    string updatescore = 
        "UPDATE `score` SET `PlayerScore`= '" + score +
        "' WHERE `ScoreID`= '" + playersid + "'";
    MySqlConnection conn2 = dbPlayer.GetConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(updatescore, conn2);
            

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
                
        MessageBox.Show("New highscore recorded", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New highscore not recorded \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    conn2.Close();

}
```

I am unsure as to why my database (Mysql) in `phpmyadmin` is not updating even though I am receiving that the new high score was recorded..

I tried using add with value and add value but it does not seem to work as well

Comment: See if ID you are using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

well, these are "trivial things", first the use of try/catch works so :

you `try` a code, the if the code has a mistake, the catch is called. So you need to put all the code if you wish to catch anything. The surprising thing is you can reach the try.

for try/catch, just put as following :

```cs
private void UpdatePlayerScore(PlayerScore phsc)
{
            

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        string updatescore = "UPDATE `score` SET `PlayerScore`= '"+ score +"' WHERE `ScoreID`='" + playersid + "'";
        MySqlConnection conn2 = dbPlayer.GetConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(updatescore, conn2);

                
        MessageBox.Show("New highscore recorded", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New highscore not recorded \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    conn2.Close();

}
```

Secondly your query :

```cs
string updatescore = "UPDATE `score` SET `PlayerScore`= '"+ score +"' WHERE `ScoreID`='" + playersid + "'";
```

It may look more like that :

```cs
string updatescore = "UPDATE score SET PlayerScore="+ score +" WHERE ScoreID=" + playersid;
```

if PlayerScore was a string, then :

```cs
string updatescore = "UPDATE score SET PlayerScore=\'"+ score +"\' WHERE ScoreID=" + playersid;
```

In fact, you always need to add a backslash before apostrophe.